# Error after installing the SPFx environment for the first time

Tags: office-365, spfx-webparts, nodejs, gulp

Got a following error after installing the SPFx environment for the first time

any help would be helpful. Thanks in Advance.

[image]

Comment: couple of things to check - 1) execute the `yo @microsoft/sharepoint` generator as admin 2) If you are inside a firewall, can you try it outside ? or try using a different network ?

Answer (score 0):

Check what is your NodeJS version

> NodeJS has two LTS versions - 8 and 10. The current supported LTS
>   version of NodeJS for the SharePoint Framework is 8.x and can be
>   downloaded from https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/. Notice that
>   9.x or 10.x versions are currently not supported with SharePoint Framework development.

If you NodeJS version is 8.x and still facing issue, Ran install command manually.

```
npm install @microsoft/sp-build-web
```

Also try to run 'npm install --save-dev' on your project folder.

```
npm install --save-dev
```

if above 2 does not work, check this [link](https://www.sharepointsky.com/cannot-find-module-microsoft-sp-build-web/) it some other solutions also.

Hope this helps...happy coding!!!

Comment: Hi Siddharth,
                     I tried all the options which you suggested but still getting the error this time from the module.js file

Comment: What is your nodejs version

Comment: My nodejs version is 8.11.4

Comment: can you run command 'npm install --save-dev' on folder and then try ? it seems your dependency is not installed.

Comment: Yes i have the same doubt while installing yo @microsoft/sharepoint I got some errors in the cmd prompt. I  have added the screenshot in the answer section

Comment: for below error you need to set your python environment variable to to point to python exe.....

Comment: is there any steps or link to do that?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/143119/how-do-i-add-python-to-the-windows-path

Answer (score 0):

Try this might be helpful

https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/15

If it's not working then please uninstall nodejs and reinstall from scratch and try.

Thanks